# Oracle Data Access Dll is not working

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I just reformatted my pc into Windows 7 64bits. I open my previous project (Always in ANY CPU) and run it, but I encountered this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Attempt to load Oracle client
>   libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when
>   running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components
>   installed. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to
>   load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007000B)

I have already installed Oracle Client win64_11gR2_client and it is in 64bits. Any Idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`Oracle.ODP` has unmanaged code and requires the owning process to match the 'bitness'.

You need to ensure that when compiling your program  as AnyCPU, that it runs in a 64-bit environment to match your 64-bit driver's bitness. You can check your TaskManager to see if your program has a `* 32` next to the process name (Means the app runs in a 32 bit context).

The bitness mismatch usually happens when you're trying to debug an application with Visual Studio on a x-64 OS.

You can solve it by installing the x86 driver of `Oracle.ODP`.

If you are sure that you only need to support x64 bit environment, compile with as x64 instead of AnyCPU.

Comment: I already installed the driver. But still encounter the issue. I using System.Data....I believe this is the one cause the problem, and there is no 64bits for this assembly... Any Idea?

Comment: System.Data.OracleClient or what? What exactly are you doing when the error occurs? Debugging or Running the compiled assembly somewhere else?